# How to design, create and read a class with xml for a unity game with C#

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a game like the "choose your own adventure books" using unity.

I thought it would be interesting to create a class for every interaction with an index, a question and the possible answers. Something like this: (simplification)

```
class Interaction
{
int index;
string question;
string optA;
string optB;
}
```

There would be hundreds of interactions.

First of all, If this is a bad idea for the structure of the game just tell me because I'm new to this and I'll change now that I can.

If this is allright, How could I store the information of all the interactions in an XML file (if it's a good solution to store all the info) and how can I make unity read the XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically want is to seperate data from logic. This is good practice (almost every program will do this) since the data would only bloat your logic.
You can store (serialize) and retrieve (deserialize) data in every format thinkable: SQL-database, binary, csv, json, xml and so on.

Since serialization itself is a rather large topic I recommend you to start with [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/serialization-and-game-data) tutorial from the unity learning section (essential the same you´re trying to do, just with json).